# Unity Проблемы с отображением градусов в отладчике

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему вместо нормальных градусов(как на первом скрине, отображение в отладчике градусы другие, чутка не удобно работать)? вообще как это исправить(без всех переустановок если возможно)?

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В eulerAngles написаны градусы поворота, такие как в инспекторе юнити, только они будут положительными(не -7, а 353), можете использовать их

Comment: да про это я знаю про eulerAngles  , вопрос в другом если мне нужен промежуток?? (тип что он <= 7 но >= -7 допустим)